# Laravel Raw Query Builder: select id by condition max() at datetime column

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a problem here. I have to get the channels, and in these channels have field content_id and began_at time of the content belong to this channel.

So the problem is I can get `max(began_at)` but I can not get the content_id. How can I get the content_id by `max(began_at)` in selectRaw()?

My query:

```
 $channels = \DB::table('channels')
            ->selectRaw('
                channels.*,
                max(contents.began_at) as latest_message_time
                ')
            ->join('subscriptions', static function (JoinClause $join) use ($device_id) {
                $join->on('subscriptions.channel_id', '=', 'channels.channel_id')
                    ->where('device_id', $device_id);
            })
            ->join('contents', static function (JoinClause $join) {
                $join->on('contents.channel_id', '=', 'subscriptions.channel_id');
            })
            ->join('content_user', static function (JoinClause $join) {
                $join->on('contents.content_id', '=', 'content_user.content_id');
                $join->on('subscriptions.user_id', '=', 'content_user.user_id');
            })
            ->orderByDesc('latest_message_time')
            ->groupBy('channels.channel_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: `max()` would return for the column provided. May be `select content_id order by began_at desc`

Comment: Thank you, it is not working. when selecting like this I need to groupBy content_id, but I have to get one content_id (the latest content_id where began_at is max)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `->orderByDesc('latest_message_time')` immediately as `latest_message_time`  field was created on the query. instead of `orderByDesc`.

use `->orderByRaw("max(contents.began_at) DESC")`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it is ok, my code is running good :D, it can orderByDesc('latest_message_time'). but can i get the content_id corresponding max('contents.began_at).